How to repeat a previously typed word in vim after inserting another character
Say I type foo in insert mode and want to insert (foo with a brace in another place.
The dot command . doesn't repeat foo in that case, but (.
How can I repeat the typing of foo?

The dot register stores only the last change.
When you do another editing operation, it's gone.
So there's no way to access a previous value of ..
What you ask for is not possible unless you somehow insert "foo" again.
The fastest way to do so would be to have the cursor on "foo" and do dwp to delete and immediately put "foo" back.
This will populate the . register with "foo", again.
However, this buys you little in comparison with good ol' copy-and-paste:
After repeating "foo" and prefixing it with a parenthesis, do wyw to yank "foo" to the unnamed register.
Afterwards, you can press p to insert it.
If you need to put "foo" several times and don't want to pay attention to the contents of the unnamed register, pick any of the 26 named ones.
E.g. to yank to register f (for foo), do "fyw and put it with "fp.
See :help . for the dot command and :help registers for more information on all the registers.

You could simply use insert mode completion:
(f<C-n>

Where :help i_ctrl-n triggers a completion popup menu that you can use with :help popupmenu-keys.
See :help ins-completion for all the kinds of completion you can get and how to trigger them.
